# cfloop inserts "YES" into page

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I'm creating a new array using `cfloop` and for some reason ColdFusion injects the word "YES" into a page HTML for every value in `MyNewArray`. So with the code below I get this "YES YES YES YES YES". How can I stop that?

```
<cfset MyNewArray = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfset MyNewArray2 = ArrayNew(1)>

<cfset MyNewArray[1] = "Sunday">
<cfset MyNewArray[2] = "Monday">
<cfset MyNewArray[3] = "Tuesday">
<cfset MyNewArray[4] = "Wednesday">
<cfset MyNewArray[5] = "Thursday">
<cfset MyNewArray[6] = "Friday">
<cfset MyNewArray[7] = "Saturday">

<cfloop from="2" to="6" index="i">
    <cfoutput>#ArrayAppend(MyNewArray2, MyNewArray[i])#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayAppend), ArrayAppend returns a boolean - i.e. true/yes - which you are outputting by wrapping the expression in `#hashes#`.

You do not need to output (or indeed do anything with the result), you can just do this:

```
<cfloop from="2" to="6" index="i">
    <cfset ArrayAppend(MyNewArray2, MyNewArray[i]) />
</cfloop>
```

As a side note, a simpler way to the same thing as your code does is use [duplicate](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/duplicate) to copy the array, then [ArrayDeleteAt](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayDeleteAt) to remove the first value.

```
<cfset MyNewArray2 = duplicate(MyNewArray) />
<cfset ArrayDeleteAt(MyNewArray2,1) />
<cfset ArrayDeleteAt(MyNewArray2,6) />
```

Or, as Leigh points out in the comments, even simpler still is converting those three lines into a single [ArraySlice](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySlice) call:

```
<cfset MyNewArray2 = ArraySlice(MyNewArray,2,5) />
```

Also consider whether [DayOfWeekAsString](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DayOfWeekAsString) is a useful function for whatever you're doing.

Comment: Re: *As a side note, a simpler way to the same thing..* .. or since you are using CF10, you can take advantage of [ArraySlice](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySlice): ie `<cfset myNewArray2 = ArraySlice(myNewArray,1,5) />`

Comment: Good point, I'd forgot CF had that - though second arg should be `2` right?

Comment: Yep, you are right. I was doing java today and forgot to switch gears :) The correct CF syntax is: `<cfset myNewArray2 = ArraySlice(myNewArray,2,5)>`